# selecting each individual button from the to toggle a css class but when I do only the last item in the list is shown in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The following is the code for my component

```
import React from 'react'
import Wrapper from '../../assets/css/LandingPageSmallerSectionCss/faqSectioncss'
// import FaqComponent from '../../components/faqComponent'
import faqs from '../../utils/faqs'

const FaqSection = () => {
    const ref = React.createRef();
    const toggleHandler = (e) => {
         e.preventDefault()
         ref.current.classList.toggle('.show-more')
     }
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <div className="faq-container">
                <h1 className="faqs-header" style={{ color: "rgb(40, 102, 129)" }}>FAQs</h1>
                <div className="list-container">
                    <ul>
                        {faqs.map((faq) => {
                            const { id, question, answer } = faq
                            return (
                                <li key={id}>
                                    <p>{question}</p>
                                    <button className="toggle-more-btn" onClick={toggleHandler}></button>
                                    <p className="faq-text" ref={ref}>{answer}</p>
                                </li>
                            )
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}

export default FaqSection
```

I can implement the code for toggling in pure javascript and plain html but i'm having trouble translating it to react since react does not have *queryselectorAll* hence i'm having trouble,the following is the code for the pure javascript

```
let listContent= document.querySelectorAll('.faq-text')
let buttonContent = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-more-btn')
const listArray=Array.from(listContent)
const buttonArray=Array.from(buttonContent)

//display both array list

// console.log(listArray)
// console.log(buttonArray)

//check if individual examples buttons are coherent with each other

// if (buttonArray[0] && listArray[0]) {
//     buttonArray[0].addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
//         listArray[0].classList.toggle('poopoo')
//     })
// }
// if (buttonArray[1] && listArray[1]) {
//     buttonArray[1].addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
//         listArray[1].classList.toggle('poopoo')
//     })
// }

//loop through all buttons in the list and if both the index of the button and list match
// for (let i = 0; i < buttonArray.length; i++) {
//     if (buttonArray[i]&&listArray[i]) {
//      buttonArray[i].addEventListener('click',e=>{
//      listArray[i].classList.toggle('poopoo')
//        })}   
// }


// create funcion that works with individual array indexes
//experimental

const buttonPress=(button,list)=>{
    for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
        if (button[i]&&list[i]) {
            button[i].addEventListener('click',e=>{
                list[i].classList.toggle('show-more')
                button[i].classList.toggle('rotate-btn')
            })
        }
    }
}
buttonPress(buttonArray,listArray)
```

I've spent hours on this.
If anyone could answer me i'd be greatfull,kindly?

Comment: First hint from just viewing the code: `toggleHandler` appears to be your handler (whether or not it is implemented correctly, IDK w/o running it), but then your `onClick` calls the non-existent `handleToggle`.

Comment: Also, your button has no text. And, if this is modern React you could use `sx` instead of `style` where you are for some reason in-lining a color (I find that just a little confusing because otherwise you're using `className(s)` everywhere. You got me playing around here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-dust-60qdm0

Comment: As for the `handleToggle` i've edited the question from `toggleHandler`,thanks for the clarification. As for the matter pertaining `style` and `sx`,I was experimenting and using old documentation. As per the `className(s)` I have used numerous of them because I am using react styled components. I thank you very much for the assistance, I will post you're code snippet so that it may help others. Again thank you very much and be blessed @NeilGaetanoLindberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a couple things so far:

1. Handler function is not named the same as what is called.
2. The DOT on your css class `.show-more`! It took awhile (and a console.log to find this).
3. I don't think you want a `ref` in the first place.

Here is what I might do using some hooks. I'm faking first load with the useEffect, with empty array arg.
Then, I'm going to set the changed faq entry in a clone of the list "faqs", and then spread my temp array into the `setFaqs`. This is using the `useState` hook, which generally you give a variable name and then a setter function name (and for these built-ins React takes care of actually setting up in the background - including the default I have an empty array).

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const mockServerReturn = [
  { id: 0, question: "Foo?", answer: "Bar!" },
  { id: 1, question: "Baz?", answer: "Bar!" },
  { id: 2, question: "Bar?", answer: "Bar!" }
];

const FaqSection = () => {
  const [faqs, setFaqs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => setFaqs(mockServerReturn), []);

  const toggleHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const temp = [...faqs];
    temp[e.target.id].chosen = !temp[e.target.id].chosen;
    setFaqs([...temp]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="faq-container">
        <h1 className="faqs-header">FAQs</h1>
        <div className="list-container">
          <ul>
            {faqs.map((faq) => {
              const { id, question, answer, chosen } = faq;
              return (
                <li key={id}>
                  <p>{question}</p>
                  <button
                    className="toggle-more-btn"
                    onClick={toggleHandler}
                    id={id}
                  >
                    I choose {id}
                  </button>
                  <p className={`faq-text${chosen ? " show-more" : ""}`}>
                    {id}:{answer}:{chosen?.toString()}
                  </p>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FaqSection />
    </div>
  );
}
```